# ASP MVC3 design pattern for persisting collection of items in a View while adding a new item to it from another View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, design-patterns

Is there a good design pattern for solving the application scenario when to an existing collection of items, displayed in a “ListItem” View, needs to be added a new Item, entered in another “NewItem”  View?

For example, An ASP.NET MVC3 with EF4.1 Code First application manages a list of products and each product contains a list of parts.  The EF model includes a Product object with several basic type  properties and a collection of Part objects.

A user can add a new Product to the list, opening a NewProductView and   enter the general product info and after that enter the collection of parts to this new Product. The Part info is collected in another NewPart View and needs to be included to the already existing collection of Parts for the new Product. The main challenge is what the best practice to persist this temp collection of Parts is, while going back and forth between   the NewProduct View and NewPart View?

One option is to save the new Part record immediately to the database, but the parent Product object is not yet built and will require several database calls. Ideally, the complete new Product object, with its collection of Parts, should be saved in one call. Another option is to use the session for a temporary Part collection storage, but I am sure if this is a good approach. At this moment I am interesting in design patterns without usage of Ajax or other client site technologies, just standard get/post to the server from the Views.

Answer (score 0):

"Ideally, the complete new Product object, with its collection of Parts, should be saved in one call." Personally I would do this with ajax, it's totally possible and not difficult, when used in combination with Steve Sanderson's [BeginCollectionItem](http://nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem) and jquery UI dialogs. However, to accomplish this without using ajax, you could do something like this:

User starts out on Product form. On the product form, there is an (empty) list of current parts along with a New Part button.

When user clicks the New Part button, submit a full postback to the action method (so the New Part button is something like `<input type="submit" name="TakeAction" value="New Part" />`.

The action method inspects the request to figure out what button was clicked. If the New Part button was clicked, the action method will return a Part form view.

However, the Part form view should have hidden fields for all of the scalar fields that could have been entered in the Product form. Also, it would have a submit button like this: `<input type="submit" name="TakeAction" value="Add Part" />`

When you submit the Part form, the action method would then return a Product form view. However, the list of current parts now contains the part that was added, along with hidden fields for all of the scalars of that Part that were entered in the previous Part form. (for more information on submitting lists of items over HTTP POST in MVC2+, see [this link](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) and [this link](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).)

This is essentially what viewstate does in webforms to maintain state across multiple user clicks. Behind the scenes, all of the data from previous form submits is carried across a series of postbacks without using session or persistent storage. In MVC, since there is no viewstate, you have to be more explicit and actually write out the "other form's" hidden fields to pass them from one form view to another across a series of postbacks.

However, as soon as your Product form gains more "collection" properties, this can get way out of hand quickly.

Another thing you could do is force users into a progressive disclosure / wizard-like workflow for creating Products and Parts. You could require the user to enter all required Product info first. Then, when that Product is saved, push them to another screen to loop over adding new Parts to the product. This gets you out of the tangled mess of interdependent principal & dependent form views that push data to each other.